# Download multiple files with cookies using python

Tags: python, selenium, wget

I want to download multiple files using python. So I use `wget` package. But I need to attach cookies to my request. How can I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that [`wget`](https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget/src/default/) module lacks this functionality. It worth noting that this project's last commit is in 2015 and it didn't develop ever since.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#install) module in python to achieve what you have in mind:

```py
import requests

urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
filenames = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']

cookies = dict(foo='bar')

for url, filename in zip(urls, filenames):
    r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(r.content)
```